# Getting different LRC (Long Range Checksum) result

Tags: c#, checksum, lrc

I'm trying to send a request to a TCP/IP terminal. My LRC function as below:

```
public byte GetLRC(byte[] bArr)
    {
        byte LRC = 0x00;
        foreach (byte b in bArr)
        {
            LRC ^= b;
        }
        return LRC;
    }
```

But the problem is my LRC and their sample LRC are totally different. How can they calculate this?

My message data request is almost the same as their except the LRC.

Sample data:

Hex: `0 66  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  32  34  31  30  33  30  30  31  30  1C  54  32  0   2   30  31  1C  34  33  0   1   30  1C  34  30  0   12  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  31  1C  34  32  0   12  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  1C  79`

Bytes:

```
{byte[68]}
[0]: 0
[1]: 102
[2]: 48
[3]: 48
[4]: 48
[5]: 48
[6]: 48
[7]: 48
[8]: 48
[9]: 48
[10]: 50
[11]: 52
[12]: 49
[13]: 48
[14]: 51
[15]: 48
[16]: 48
[17]: 49
[18]: 48
[19]: 28
[20]: 84
[21]: 50
[22]: 0
[23]: 2
[24]: 48
[25]: 49
[26]: 28
[27]: 52
[28]: 51
[29]: 0
[30]: 1
[31]: 48
[32]: 28
[33]: 52
[34]: 48
[35]: 0
[36]: 18
[37]: 48
[38]: 48
[39]: 48
[40]: 48
[41]: 48
[42]: 48
[43]: 48
[44]: 48
[45]: 48
[46]: 48
[47]: 48
[48]: 49
[49]: 28
[50]: 52
[51]: 50
[52]: 0
[53]: 18
[54]: 48
[55]: 48
[56]: 48
[57]: 48
[58]: 48
[59]: 48
[60]: 48
[61]: 48
[62]: 48
[63]: 48
[64]: 48
[65]: 48
[66]: 28
[67]: 121
```

My data:

```
0   66  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  32  34  31  30  33  30  30  31  30  1C  54  32  0   2   30  31  1C  34  33  0   1   30  1C  34  30  0   12  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  31  1C  34  32  0   12  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  1C  1F

{byte[68]}
[0]: 0
[1]: 102
[2]: 48
[3]: 48
[4]: 48
[5]: 48
[6]: 48
[7]: 48
[8]: 48
[9]: 48
[10]: 50
[11]: 52
[12]: 49
[13]: 48
[14]: 51
[15]: 48
[16]: 48
[17]: 49
[18]: 48
[19]: 28
[20]: 84
[21]: 50
[22]: 0
[23]: 2
[24]: 48
[25]: 49
[26]: 28
[27]: 52
[28]: 51
[29]: 0
[30]: 1
[31]: 48
[32]: 28
[33]: 52
[34]: 48
[35]: 0
[36]: 18
[37]: 48
[38]: 48
[39]: 48
[40]: 48
[41]: 48
[42]: 48
[43]: 48
[44]: 48
[45]: 48
[46]: 48
[47]: 48
[48]: 49
[49]: 28
[50]: 52
[51]: 50
[52]: 0
[53]: 18
[54]: 48
[55]: 48
[56]: 48
[57]: 48
[58]: 48
[59]: 48
[60]: 48
[61]: 48
[62]: 48
[63]: 48
[64]: 48
[65]: 48
[66]: 28
[67]: 31
```

[image]

Comment: Their algorithm could be different. Please provide data and expected `checksum` so that we can think of alternative algorithm.

Comment: @MKR Thanks for reply. I've just edited my question.

Comment: Can you please send me another packet for which LRC is available so that I can verify logic?

Comment: Hi, @MKR that's all what I have. I expected LRC 121(79 in hex) but with the   algorithm above I always get LRC 31(1F in hex).

Comment: If you use `MD5` and compute hash using `ComputeHash()' function on their data then 2nd byte of HASH will match with their LRC code. I'm still wondering why they would have done something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MKR. I'm currently working in Singapore. And this is Nets Terminal Integration. I had no problem with their Serial Port Terminal before until they came out the Network Terminal which I have to communicate via TCP/IP.